# Добавление строки .txt

Tags: c#

Оно вечно перезаписывает текст, а мне нужно что бы оно добавляло.
Пробовал File.AppendAllText() но оно не пускает

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\test.txt"))
    {

        myWriter.WriteLineAsync(textBox2.Text);
        myWriter.WriteLineAsync(textBox3.Text);
        myWriter.WriteLineAsync(textBox4.Text);
        myWriter.WriteLineAsync(textBox5.Text);
        myWriter.WriteLineAsync(textBox6.Text);
        myWriter.WriteLineAsync(textBox7.Text);
        myWriter.WriteLineAsync(textBox8.Text);
        myWriter.WriteLineAsync(textBox9.Text);
        myWriter.WriteLineAsync(openFileDialog1.FileName);

    }
    MessageBox.Show("Питання успішно додане");

}
```

Comment: Что означает «но оно не пускает»?

Comment: Добавьте `true` в конструктор чтобы получилось вот так -  `new StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\test.txt", true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("myFile.txt"))
{
  w.WriteLine("hello");
}
```

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837020/open-existing-file-append-a-single-line) много других вариантов.